# How to implement loadView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, loadview

I've created a custom view called `GraphView`. All I get is a blank black screen when the view is loaded. Here is my code:

in GraphViewController.m:

```
@synthesize graphView, graphModel;

- (void)loadView
{   
    GraphView *aGraphView = [[GraphView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.view = aGraphView;
    self.graphView = aGraphView;

    [aGraphView release];
}
```

I'm not sure why I just get a black screen when I try to implement `loadView` in `GraphViewController.m`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to make the background color white in `loadView`

```
- (void)loadView
{   
    GraphView *aGraphView = [[GraphView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    aGraphView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.view = aGraphView;
    self.graphView = aGraphView;

    [aGraphView release];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting a frame for the `GraphView` object:

`GraphView *aGraphView = [[GraphView alloc] init];`

The designated initializer for `UIView`'s is `-initWithFrame:`. Do something like this (setting the size/origin of the view as you desire):

`GraphView *aGraphView = [[GraphView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];`

Comment: I made the indicated changes and it still just shows a blank black screen.

Comment: I commented out `loadView` and now it works even though I deleted the .xib file that I was using before. I'm confused as to how it could work without a .xib or a `loadView`

Comment: You need to clean the deployed app as well. Delete the application on the simulator or device. Clean all targets. Run application. Then you'll see how its working.

Comment: how do I 'clean all targets, etc.' ?

Comment: Okay I made a new project and copied the files and now when I comment out loadView I get a blank white screen. If i Implement loadView, then I get a blank black screen. I'll post my `graphView.m`